# OpenID Connect security issues

Tags: attacks, openid-connect

Recently, I started to wonder if OpenID Connect is really secure enough. I have analyzed tons of different sites and official documentation and so far I don't see any problems except that stealing user sessions from one client can lead an attacker to gain access to all clients that the user is logged on to. I am not able to notice any more problems, no matter how small. If there are any, I would like someone to introduce them to me so that I can get acquainted with this protocol better. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a way broad question. OpenID may have security issues by "itself" just like any other product, but the way it's implemented can indeed lead to a very vast range of potential issues

Comment: Assuming everything is implemented as per official documentation. So what security problems may arise? What are the possible successful attacks?